# Looking for more efficient way to perform this calculation

Tags: r

I have a list containing vectors of words that are of varying length. I want to create a data frame that contains information about the overlap between each of these word vectors in relation to the others.

I have a double for loop right now, that checks how many words are in each of the other entries with sum(l[i] %in% l[j]) if i is not equal to j

My current method appears to be inefficient, but it does provide the right answer. What is the most R way to do this?

```
l = list()
l <- c(l,list(c("word","another","hi","words")))
l <- c(l,list(c("word","maybe","nope")))
l <- c(l,list(c("maybe","nope")))
df <- data.frame(index = 0,one = 0,two = 0)
for(i in 1:length(l)){
  df <- rbind(df,data.frame(index = i,one = 0,two = 0))
  for(j in 1:length(l)){
    if(i == j){next}
    truth_vec <- sum(l[[i]] %in% l[[j]])
    if(truth_vec == 1){df[i + 1,]$one = df[i + 1,]$one + 1}
    else if(truth_vec == 2){df[i + 1,]$two = df[i + 1,]$two + 1}
    else{NULL}
  }
}
```

Comment: @thelatemail, you should post as answer

Comment: @ChiPak - I was hoping for some clarification from OP first on what they want as output.

Comment: True, it's still a nice answer, even if the format is not quite what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could look for the `intersection` of each pairwise combination of `l`:

```
combn(l, 2, FUN=function(x) length(intersect(x[[1]],x[[2]])) )
#[1] 1 0 2
```

Where 1 overlap when (i=1,j=2), 0 when (i=1,j=3), and 2 when (i=2,j=3).

Comment: It's important that I can access the id's in an easy way in the data frame